# How to append Change-id to commit message inside custom commit-msg hook?

Tags: python, git, hook, gerrit

I've prepared my own commit message template and commit-msg hook for validation purposes. This hook is a simple Python script. It works but I'd like to have also Change-id at the bottom of my commit message.
I see that from gerrit I can download commit-msg hook which is written in Bash and this hook provides solution for Change-id generation:
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html.
But now I have 2 different commit-msg hooks. So should I rewrite my own  msg-hook and append it to that official msg-hook template or maybe I should write my own implementation of Change-id generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify the `MSG` variable definition at the beginning of the original commit-msg hook by replacing `$1` input param with your script output

```
#!/bin/sh
# From Gerrit Code Review 2.14.20-179-g6c46f4efba
#
# Part of Gerrit Code Review (https://www.gerritcodereview.com/)
#
# Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

unset GREP_OPTIONS

CHANGE_ID_AFTER="Bug|Depends-On|Issue|Test|Feature|Fixes|Fixed"
MSG=`python /path/to/myscript.py`

# Check for, and add if missing, a unique Change-Id
#
add_ChangeId() {
        clean_message=`sed -e '
```

Comment: What is that MSG parameter? My python script output is 0 - validation passed or 1 - validation failed.

Comment: MSG variable contains the commit message - which is by default the first input parameter of the commit-msg script. So your final commit message will be 0 - validation passed and the change-id